# Align subcaption to its subtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to create a table with tree subtables in it. To do so I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document} % <---
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Producción} \\ \hline
Metabolito      & Valor      & Metabolito       & Valor       \\ \hline
D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & CO\textsubscript{2}              & 22,81               
\\
Amonio          & 4,77       & H\textsubscript{2}O              & 29,18           
\\
Fosfato         & 3,21       & H\textsuperscript{+}               & 17,53       
\\
O\textsubscript{2}              & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.1}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Producción} \\ \hline
Metabolito      & Valor      & Metabolito       & Valor       \\ \hline
D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & CO\textsubscript{2}              & 22,81       \\
Amonio          & 4,77       & H\textsubscript{2}O              & 29,18       \\
Fosfato         & 3,21       & H\textsuperscript{+}               & 17,53       \\
O\textsubscript{2}              & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.2}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}[]{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{15pt}\hspace{0.5\linewidth}\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Producción} \\ \hline
Metabolito      & Valor      & Metabolito       & Valor       \\ \hline
D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & CO\textsubscript{2}              & 22,81       \\
Amonio          & 4,77       & H\textsubscript{2}O              & 29,18       \\
Fosfato         & 3,21       & H\textsuperscript{+}               & 17,53       \\
O\textsubscript{2}              & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038      \\ \hline
\end{tabular} \caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.3}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Resultados de las distintas simulaciones}
\end{table}
\end{document}% <---
```

The problem is that the third subtable is not aligned with its caption:

[image]

Is there any easy solution to align them?

Comment: Yes. See the `subcaption` manual for options. Set alignment for all sub-figures or just sub-tables, as you wish. Never use `h` alone as a float specifier. Where is LaTeX meant to put it if it *doesn't* fit? `h` means 'here, if it fits'. Please make your code compilable.

Comment: remove `\vspace{15pt}\hspace{0.5\linewidth}` from third `subtable`. however each of your table is wider than `0.5\textwidth` (in page layout as is in your code example), so equation overlap (if i test your code) or tables are in one column if test your code after considering aforementioned suggestion. also i take liberty and make your code compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your tables are wider than width of `\subtable`, consequently using your *mwe* (after adding missing parts of code, see my comment above) your tables overlaps (red lines on image below indicate your page layout):

[image]

- considering my suggestion in comment above, you will obtain:

[image]

- if i increase text width with use of the package `geometry` (using its default page layout settings) than i obtain after some small tweak of your `subtable` size, i obtain:

[image]

**Edit:**
code, where is for chemical formulas used the `mhchem` package,  for the last case is:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % <---
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % <--- new

%-------------------------------- show page layout, don't use in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\centering
\begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Producción} \\ \hline
Metabolito      & Valor      & Metabolito       & Valor         \\ \hline
D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & \ce{CO2}         & 22,81         \\
Amonio          & 4,77       & \ce{H2O}         & 29,18         \\
Fosfato         & 3,21       & \ce{H+}          & 17,53         \\
\ce{O2}         & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.1}
\end{subtable}
    \hfil
\begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Producción} \\ \hline
Metabolito      & Valor      & Metabolito       & Valor         \\ \hline
D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & \ce{CO2}         & 22,81         \\
Amonio          & 4,77       & \ce{H2O}         & 29,18         \\
Fosfato         & 3,21       & \ce{H+}          & 17,53         \\
\ce{O2}         & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.2}
\end{subtable}

\medskip
\begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Producción} \\ \hline
Metabolito      & Valor      & Metabolito       & Valor         \\ \hline
D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & \ce{CO2}         & 22,81         \\
Amonio          & 4,77       & \ce{H2O}         & 29,18         \\
Fosfato         & 3,21       & \ce{H+}          & 17,53         \\
\ce{O2}         & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.3}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Resultados de las distintas simulaciones}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost synchronized! The answers are a bit different, so I can leave mine :):):)

Answer (score 2):

Putting an empty line before the last subtable and adding a `\centering` would do the trick.

Your MWE isn't complete, if I only add `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` the subtables overlap, I can't reproduce your output, and I get `overfull hbox`. Hence I changed it a bit:

1. I've used the font `\footnotesize`
2. I've removed the vertical space before the first column and after the last one
3. I've used `booktabs` package for horizontal lines
4. and `dcolumn` for the alignment of the numbers.

Here is the result:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{,}{#1}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{font=footnotesize,labelfont={footnotesize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]\footnotesize\centering
    \begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ld{2}ld{4}@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Producción}\\ 
            \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
            Metabolito & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Valor}      & Metabolito       & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{Valor}       \\ 
            \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
            D-Fructosa & 10,00      & CO\textsubscript{2} & 22,81\\
            Amonio & 4,77       & H\textsubscript{2}O & 29,18\\
            Fosfato & 3,21       & H\textsuperscript{+}& 17,53\\
            O\textsubscript{2} & 22,00   & Acetato          & 0,0038      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.1}
    \end{subtable}
    \hfill
    \begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ld{2}ld{4}@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Producción} \\ 
            \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
            Metabolito      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Valor}      & Metabolito       & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{Valor}       \\ 
            \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
            D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & CO\textsubscript{2}              & 22,81       \\
            Amonio          & 4,77       & H\textsubscript{2}O              & 29,18       \\
            Fosfato         & 3,21       & H\textsuperscript{+}               & 17,53       \\
            O\textsubscript{2}              & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.2}
    \end{subtable}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{subtable}{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ld{2}ld{4}@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Consumo} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Producción} \\
            \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
            Metabolito      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Valor}      & Metabolito       & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{Valor}       \\ 
            \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
            D-Fructosa      & 10,00      & CO\textsubscript{2}              & 22,81       \\
            Amonio          & 4,77       & H\textsubscript{2}O              & 29,18       \\
            Fosfato         & 3,21       & H\textsuperscript{+}               & 17,53       \\
            O\textsubscript{2}              & 22,00      & Acetato          & 0,0038      \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular} 
        \caption{\textit{E.coli} con fuente de carbono fructosa}\label{tabla4.3}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Resultados de las distintas simulaciones}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice answer (+1)! and distinct different from mine :-)