# Several tables with their own captions

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to place Butcher Tableau like on the screenshot[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the `subcaption` package.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405418.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As starting point, based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405386/align-subcaption-to-its-subtable):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\centering
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\[
\begin{array}{l|l}
    \hline
0   &   0   \\ \hline
    &   1   \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\caption{Euler Forward}
\end{subtable}
    \hfil
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\[
\begin{array}{l|l}
    \hline
0   &   0   \\ \hline
    &   1   \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\caption{Euler Forward}
\end{subtable}
    \hfil
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\[
\begin{array}{l|l}
    \hline
0   &   0   \\ \hline
    &   1   \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\caption{Euler Forward}
\end{subtable}

\medskip
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\[
\begin{array}{l|l}
    \hline
0   &   0   \\ \hline
    &   1   \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\caption{Euler Forward}
\end{subtable}
    \hfil
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\[
\begin{array}{l|l}
    \hline
0   &   0   \\ \hline
    &   1   \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\caption{Euler Forward}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Butcher's Tableaus}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

I left to write real tables in sub tables to you.

Comment: Thank you very much!